# Installing UBUNTU 12.04 on ASUS Zenbook UX32A

Tags: installation, windows, live-usb, asus

I used to use UBUNTU on my old pc. I have just bought my first laptop an ASUS UX32A.

I have created a USB (working one i hope) I am not sure how to go about doing this and where I should down load it.
I have considered 3 options

1 putting it in a partition on the OS half of main drive.
2 putting on the 24G SSD drive 
3 removing windows 8 completely and putting it in its place.

I have a few concerns about losing ASUS software and losing windows 8 completely.

What is the best option for me?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since i bought a new PC, but Ive always had restore disks with OS and manufacture software, if you have that I see no reason why you would loose windows or ASUS software (I may be wrong - Ive never had to use those diks).

Do you want Windows 8 / will you use it?, If you're sure that you will only need ubuntu then there would be no reason to keep it.

The advantage of putting OS on SSD is access speed for system files. 24GB isn't very big, Ubuntu and program files will probably fit, your files probably won't.

Comment: Ive read about people putting it on the 24GB SSD. At moment windows